# etherpad lite api listAll failed

Tags: api, etherpad

In etherpad lite I try to list pads or groups with the api.
But I reveive the following message:

```
{"code":2,"message":"createHTTPError.notFound is not a constructor","data":null}
```

I've writen an Java-Application doing and I've tried with curl.

With Curl:

```
 curl "http://localhost:9001/api/1/listAllPads&apikey=477da...

"code":2,"message":"createHTTPError.notFound is not a constructor","data":null}

curl "http://localhost:9001/api/1/listAllGroups?apikey=477da3361...

{"code":2,"message":"createHTTPError.notFound is not a constructor","data":null}
```

Createing author, group, pad for group and session works with the api.

**Enviroment:**

Windows 10

Node.js v12.17.0

No proxy, direct access

Database postgres

Etherpad version
Version number: 1.8.4

Git sha: 6a0f73d

Installed plugins

ep_auth_session,
ep_adminpads2,
ep_etherpad-lite,
ep_message_all,
ep_headings2,
ep_real_time_chat,
ep_tables3,
ep_author_hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "createHTTPError.notFound is not a constructor"  occurred when an unsupported function is called.
The api version (1) that you have specified supports following functions only

```
 { "createGroup"               : []
  , "createGroupIfNotExistsFor" : ["groupMapper"]
  , "deleteGroup"               : ["groupID"]
  , "listPads"                  : ["groupID"]
  , "createPad"                 : ["padID", "text"]
  , "createGroupPad"            : ["groupID", "padName", "text"]
  , "createAuthor"              : ["name"]
  , "createAuthorIfNotExistsFor": ["authorMapper" , "name"]
  , "listPadsOfAuthor"          : ["authorID"]
  , "createSession"             : ["groupID", "authorID", "validUntil"]
  , "deleteSession"             : ["sessionID"]
  , "getSessionInfo"            : ["sessionID"]
  , "listSessionsOfGroup"       : ["groupID"]
  , "listSessionsOfAuthor"      : ["authorID"]
  , "getText"                   : ["padID", "rev"]
  , "setText"                   : ["padID", "text"]
  , "getHTML"                   : ["padID", "rev"]
  , "setHTML"                   : ["padID", "html"]
  , "getRevisionsCount"         : ["padID"]
  , "getLastEdited"             : ["padID"]
  , "deletePad"                 : ["padID"]
  , "getReadOnlyID"             : ["padID"]
  , "setPublicStatus"           : ["padID", "publicStatus"]
  , "getPublicStatus"           : ["padID"]
  , "listAuthorsOfPad"          : ["padID"]
  , "padUsersCount"             : ["padID"]
```

The functions, you are requesting are supported by API version 1.1 and 1.2.1.

Here, you can check complete list of functions with their respective API version
https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/blob/develop/src/node/handler/APIHandler.js

Solution: Use the api version 1.2.1 (It supports listAllGroups and listAllPads)

> curl "http://localhost:9001/api/1.2.1/listAllPads&apikey=477da...